# How to retrieve checkout information when using Stripe SDK

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

Here is my Cart and Checkout process in my web application

My purpose is after checkout, I retrieve the payment information like transaction Id or payment reference

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application, I have following code in Cart View

```
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "Cart", FormMethod.Post))
{
     ... here I show products in cart ...

     ... NOTE that I don't have any action in my form ...

     <input type="submit" id="stripe-checkout-button" value="Checkout" />
}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var stripe = Stripe('@ViewBag.StripePublishKey');
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('stripe-checkout-button');

    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        fetch('https://localhost:44323/Cart/CreateCheckoutSession', {
            method: 'POST'
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(session) {
                return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
            })
            .then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    alert(result.error.message);
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    });
</script>
```

In Cart controller I have following actions

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateCheckoutSession()
{
    var cart = (ShoppingCart)Session["cart"];
    var options = new SessionCreateOptions
    {
        PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> { "card" },
        Mode = "payment",
        SuccessUrl = Url.Action("CheckoutSuccessful", "Cart", null, Request.Url.Scheme),
        CancelUrl = Url.Action("CheckoutCancelled", "Cart", null, Request.Url.Scheme),
        PaymentIntentData = new SessionPaymentIntentDataOptions
        {
            CaptureMethod = "manual"
        },
        LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>()
    };

    foreach (var item in cart.Items)
    {
        // here I add the purchased product. I remove the code for simplification
    }

    var service = new SessionService();
    Session session = service.Create(options);

    ViewBag.SessionId = session.Id;

    return Json(new { id = session.Id });
}

public ActionResult CheckoutSuccessful(string sessionId)
{
    // sessionId is null here. I'm even not sure if I need this parameter

    ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart)Session["cart"];
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Checkout");
}

public ActionResult CheckoutCancelled()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cart");
}
```

When I click on Checkout button, the application redirects to Stripe payment page and I can enter email and billing information and click pay. It works well and payment goes through.

Based on my setting, the application redirects to CheckoutSuccessful action after that.

What I am missing here is, in CheckoutSuccessful action, I need to retrieve email address and billing address plus payment or transaction Id. I don't know how to do that.
In CheckoutSuccessful, the parameter `sessionId` is null. I don't know what I've done wrong here or what I'm missing.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days research and try out, I figured it out.

After creating `session`, I need to store the `session.Id` in Http Session and in `CheckoutSuccessful` method (which does not need any parameter), I need to call couple of APIs to retrieve session and payment information like below:

```
var service = new SessionService();
var session = service.Get(the stored session.Id);

var custService = new CustomerService();
var customer = custService.Get(session.CustomerId);

var paymentService = new PaymentIntentService();
var payment = paymentService.Get(session.PaymentIntentId);
```

Then, I will have all required infromation in `session`, `customer` and `payment` objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure that the newly created Checkout Session ID is included in your success URL by appending `{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID` to the success URL: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page#modify-success-url

Then on your success URL you can grab the Session ID from the query params and retrieve the Checkout Session.

Comment: When I do that and I change parameter of CheckoutSuccessful to (string session_id), I get session_id as {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}, not the actual value